# record type name insert in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, record-type, compile-error

- Record Type Label: `Lead/Opportunity Rule`
- Record Type Name: `Lead_Opportunity_Rule`

> throw an error Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be
>   a concrete SObject: String

```
 String recType = Schema.SObjectType.Assignment__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Lead_Opportunity_Rule').getRecordTypeId();
             //Assignment Record
                Assignment__c objass = new Assignment__c();
                objass.FE_Code__c = fobj.id;
                objass.Partner_ID__c = fobj.id;
                objass.Lead_Rule_Type__c = 'PartnerID';
                objass.RecordType = recType.name;
                insert objass;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get record type Id, you cannot extract name from it.

```
RecordType rt = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType = 'Assignment__c' AND Name = 'Lead_Opportunity_Rule'];
...
objass.RecordType = rt;
// OR
objass.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;
```

Comment: i tried this but it throw an error that List has no rows

Comment: Use DeveloperName instead of Name

Answer (score 5):

You should assign the lookup as follows:

```
objPass.RecordTypeId = recType;
```

A `String` instance does not have the `Name` property.

You might confuse yourself less with clearer naming here, using instead `recTypeId`, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Change this line `objass.RecordType = recType.name;` to this:
`objass.RecordTypeId = recType ;`