# Not able to access recordtype name of opportunity that is created in test class

Tags: unit-test

I have a trigger on opportunity object which has the code as follows:

```js
trigger Opportunity_bInsertbUpdate on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
 for(Opportunity opp:trigger.new){
   if(opp.Recordtype.Name == 'AP Subscription'){
      //Some code
   }
 }
}
```

I am writing a test method to cover the code inside the `if` condition. I am getting `opp.Recordtype.Name` as `null`.

I am setting the recordtype for opportunity in my test method as follows:

```js
Id RecordTypeIdOpp = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('AP Subscription').getRecordTypeId();
oppt.RecordtypeId = RecordTypeIdOpp ;
insert oppt;
```

I also tried setting the opportunity recordtype as follows:

```js
RecordType rt = [SELECT Id,Name FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType = 'opportunity' AND Name = 'AP Subscription' AND isActive = true LIMIT 1];
oppt.RecordtypeId = rt.Id;
insert oppt;
```

Both the methods didn't work. I am not able to set the recordtype name from the test class. I referred [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146930/record-type-name-insert-in-test-class) question. Please guide. Thank You!

Comment: In your for loop you are iterating trigger.new, recordtype.name won't we available without quering it

Comment: I would suggest use RecordTypeId

Comment: and compare based on RecordTypeId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't just a problem with a unit test, your code will behave the same way in all contexts. The only data you'll find in trigger context variables (trigger.old, trigger.newMap, etc...) is data on that object itself.

Related data, the data found on records that are *related* to a given object (like RecordType.Name which is a RecordType object related to your Opportunity), is only accessible if you explicitly query for it.

Basically, if you need more than one dot "." to access a field (you have two in `Opportunity.RecordType.Name`), you need to query for that data.

Comment: You could use a formula field to work around that, but that comes with a different set of limitations (and it's harder to work around those limitations once you hit them).

Comment: Although, instead of "query", in this case, you can just use a describe instead.